# Want to find whether location(latitude, longitude) point is moving or not?

Tags: java, collections, latitude-longitude

I have list of locations(Means latitude or longitude in arraylist) and I want to find halted and moving locations from that list. Please give me some methods to solve this situation.

```
public void find(ArrayList<Location> loclist) {
    for (int i = 0; i < loclist.size()-1; i++) {
        Location loc = loclist.get(i); // this is current location
        double lat = loc.getLatitude();
        double lng = loc.getLongitude();

        Location nextloc = loclist.get(i+1); // this is next location
        double nextlat = nextloc.getLatitude();
        double nextlng = nextloc.getLongitude();

        // now find distance between these points
        double distance = getDistance(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), nextloc.getLatitude(), nextloc.getLongitude());
        if(distance is less than 100 meters means point is halted) {
            // now put this in halted point list 
        } else {
            // add in moving point list
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by halted and moving locations? What is a halted location? What is a moving one?

Comment: Halted means latitude longitude same for more than 2 points. Means point is at same gps location.

Answer (score 0):

I think the wording of your question is a little confusing, but I believe you are trying to determine if, in a given time interval, there was movement. You can simply compare one pair of coordinates to the previous. For example,

```
ArrayList<Integer> latitude = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Boolean> moving = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
for(int i = 1; i<latitude.size(); i++)
    {
        if(latitude.get(i-1)!=latitude.get(i))
        {
            moving.set(i, true);
        }
        else
        {
            moving.set(i,false);
        }
    }
```

(Imagine that the arraylist is filled with latitude values)
Now, a new arraylist will be filled with boolean values as to whether it was moving between the previous point and the current point 'latitudinaly'.